# How to disable IntelliJ IDEA pulling repository automatically?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working on multiple projects at the same time which are inter dependent. Sometimes, when one developer pushes updates to one project (for example Liquibase changes), they are picked up by my IntelliJ which immediately complains about missing columns when I restart the project. I did not explicitly issue any fetch/pull or update request against the remote repository. This is kind of annoying because I am then forced to pull all the new changes locally.

I remember my old IntelliJ version behaving normally (2019) so this is a new "feature" I guess? How can I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share screenshots of an issue? IDE doesn't run pull/fetch or upgrade automatically if you are using Git, but there is a chance that you may have `Git Toolbox` plugin installed and it has a feature for Auto-fetch and you need to disable it in settings